# creating an object that can be accessed by all threads in dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'd like to create an object (like a shared memory) that could be accessed (read-write fashion) by all threads. Although not important for this question, the object is a hashmap that I can read/write data to from all threads. It's like a read-write shared var.

Is there a way to do this in dataflow?

In my case, I can "break" one key requirement and have this shared var to be "local" to the node that it's running on. So, if there was a way to create (for each instance node) a static var that all threads *within* a given node can access, that would work for me.

I thought that maybe I could create a static var (using a factory method) in the startBundle method, but I read somewhere that that's not recommended for streaming dataflow scenario (since there can lots of startBundle calls). So, can I maybe create it in the constructor of the ParDo? Is that acceptable? And if so, would *all* threads on a given node be able to access this static var? (I can test it of course, but it might not be an "acceptable" solution per df specs or guidelines.) Or, is there another way to do this? I'm on dataflow sdk 1.9.0

Comment: This is a bit of a strange use case. There is no guarantee that all the threads in a given node will be executing the same step, nor that all the data for a specific step will go through the same node. Could you be more specific about what you need to do? Perhaps the State API could help you. Can you elaborate on your use case?

Comment: In my case, the object is like a pseudo-cache. It's not a real cache, though, because (for max performance) I'm using a simple hashmap. In my use-case, any key in the hashmap is populated only once but can be ready milions of times. So, it doesn't matter "where any thread is" in its logic, so long as it can a) access a key in hashmap to see if the "value" has already been precomputed; if precomputed, use it; else, compute it and stick it in the hashmap so that the "next time" someone needs that value, they don't need to compute it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need shared state per machine, you can use a static variable and appropriate locking to accomplish this.

If you need to coordinate state across machines, you can try the new State API in the Apache Beam java SDK: https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html

Comment: ok cool: and I'm assuming that I should NOT put the instatiation of my object in the "startBundle" method or the "processElemet()" method, but instead I should just create a static field in my ParDo class and instantiate this static field in my ParDo's constructor?

Comment: processElement is called on each element, and startBundle is called once per bundle. Both happen multiple times per thread during processing. So you could either use a static initializer or include lazy-init logic inside one of those methods.